# Batch - check if any file have been updated in a folder

Tags: batch-file

I want to be able, to copy any file that have been updated and check every 2mins.

"updated": Like the last edit date or check the file size have been raised of something like that.

I searched on Google and I found this:

`for %%X in ("file name") do set size=%%~zX&set filetime=%%~tX`

But I don't know if i can't check in a folder with this line of code if yes, then excuse me to take your time...

Place a comment if it's not clear, I'll rewrite it.

-Briant

Answer (score 0):

Well, I thought two ways to do this:

First way is using `timeout` command to check every two minutes if file size is different from last check.
Second way is scheduling your batch script for running every two minutes and check for a before saved registry key.

The first way is best if you don't care that the script stay running all time, so here we go:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:start
call:check
if "%currentFileSize%" NEQ "" (
 if !currentFileSize! NEQ !lastFileSize! (
  echo/Here you can do whatever you want
  pause
 ) else (
  echo/Size not changed
 )
)
set lastFileSize=%currentFileSize%
timeout 120
goto start
:check
for /f %%a in ("File.txt") do (set CurrentFileSize=%%~za)
```

Comment: It works, but is it possible to target all the files into a folder, and even all the subfolders ?

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "targetdir=U:\destdir"
SET "flagfilename=%temp%\changedfiles.flag"
PUSHD %targetdir%
(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d /o:n "*" 2^>nul'
  ) DO (ECHO(%%~za-%%~ta*%%~fa)
)>"%flagfilename%"
:loop
timeout /t 10 >nul
IF NOT EXIST "%flagfilename%" popd&GOTO :EOF
(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d /o:n "*" 2^>nul'
  ) DO (ECHO(%%~za-%%~ta*%%~fa)
)>"%flagfilename%.2"

FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=*" %%a IN ('type "%flagfilename%.2" ') DO (
 FINDSTR /L /c:"*%%b" "%flagfilename%" > nul
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO new file:%%~nxb) ELSE (
  FINDSTR /x /L /c:"%%a*%%b" "%flagfilename%" > nul
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO chg file:%%~nxb)
 )
)
FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=*" %%a IN ('type "%flagfilename%" ') DO (
 FINDSTR /L /c:"*%%b" "%flagfilename%.2" > nul
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO del file:%%~nxb)
)
MOVE /y "%flagfilename%.2" "%flagfilename%" >NUL 2>NUL
GOTO loop


GOTO :EOF
```

You need to set `targetdir` to the directory of interest; set the flag file name as you choose.

Builds a list of files in the flag file, then builds and compares a companion list. Analyses and reports on the differences.

You can close the process cleanly by deleting the flag file.

I set timeout to 10 seconds for testing. Needless to say, you'd need to change the timeout to 120 for a 2-minute cycle time.

Comment: Alright, but is it possible to target all the files in a folder ?

Comment: This routine *does* target all files.

Comment: Wait, the "targetdir", I put like Folder1 because it's in the same folder, and flagfilename to like "cats.txt" ?

Comment: No idea what you're trying to say, I'm afraid. All you need do is to set `targetdir` to the directoryname that you want to monitor. The flagfilename can be whatever you like (noting that a temporary file *whatevernameyouchoose.2* will be created for a short while in the process. The idea here is that if you know the name of the temporary file, then you can terminate the process easily , just by deleting that file. If you want to monitor subdirectories too, then simply include `/s` along with the `/b` in the two `dir` commands. You need to make sure that the flagfile  is not monitored.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Vista or later OS (or if you are using XP and are allowed to use the freely downloadable 2003 Resource Kit Tools from Microsoft), robocopy is the better option

```
robocopy c:\source\folder c:\target\folder /e /mot:2
```

This will recursively copy all the files and folders from source to target and, each two minutes, if there is any change, it will be reflected in target.